# Rails rmagick error Ubuntu c9.io

Tags: rmagick

I've been looking around on other rmagick threads for a good solution. Nothing has worked so far.

I'm working on a rails project on c9 IDE. I managed to successfully install imagemagick via the 'sudo apt get install imagemagick' command.

However when I try to run 'gem install rmagick' I get the following error

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.15.4/ext/RMagick
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160608-3911-1hut05d.rb extconf.rb
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
checking for pkg-config... yes
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found checking for outdated ImageMagick version (<= 6.4.9)... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/rmagick-2.15.4/mkmf.log extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby 2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.15.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/rmagick-2.15.4/gem_make.out
```

Comment: The words in the error message *Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.* and the three lines after it don't help?

Comment: Okay, I see that but I don't know how to solve that. I dont know where it's located on c9.io terminal

Answer (score 1):

Try this (working for rmagick 3.0.0):

```
brew install imagemagick@6
brew link --force imagemagick@6
gem install rmagick
```